# move 1 vertex at a time rather than the entire shape

Tags: arcgis-10.0, editing

Somewhere I have changed settings that allow me to move 1 vertex at a time while editing a shape.  It now moves the entire shape or scales the shape! Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you need to double-click on the shape to re-enter Vertex Editing.

Vertex Editing is described [**here**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m80000003p000000).

Answer (score 2):

I think one had hit "Stretch Proportionally" in the "Edit Vertices" toolbar. With that enabled, one cannot move individual vertices without affecting the entire shape.